# Accessing information within a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I am trying to parse out data from a NSDictionary but am having trouble. Whenever I try to access this information it prints nil.

NSDictionary:

```
{
"-LTR7P8PFWHogjlBENiJ" =     {
    filmid = 335983;
    rating = "5.5";
    review = Ehh;
};
}
```

CODE:

```
let dict = info.value as! NSDictionary
print(dict) //prints about NSDict
print(dict["review"] as? String) //prints nil
```

What would be the correct method to print "Ehh" from the NSDictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `review` value as below,

```
typealias JSON = [String: Any]
let dictionary: JSON = [
    "-LTR7P8PFWHogjlBENiJ": [
        "filmid": 335983,
        "rating": "5.5",
        "review": "Ehh"
    ]
]

if let reivew = (dictionary.first?.value as? JSON)?["review"] as? String {
    print(reivew)
}
```

For `NSDictionary`, you might have to use this as below,

```
let dict = info.value as! NSDictionary
if let reivew = (dict.allValues.first as? JSON)?["review"] as? String {
    print(reivew)
}
```

Comment: What would I use to print the "-LTR7P8PFWHogjlBENiJ"?

Comment: @JSharpp you can print `print(dict.allKeys.first as? String)`

Comment: How would I display the inner wrapper only if the key is a specific value?

Comment: @JSharpp what do you mean by inner wrapper?

Comment: How would I search for each instance of "-LTR7P8PFWHogjlBENiJ" and display the data from each from each one?

Comment: That could be added as an another question because i believe you need to describe the use of this data(mean where you want to use it, `UITableView`, `UIView` etc). You might have to use `JSONDecoder` and some structure type to represent the `data`.

Answer (score 2):

You have outer dictionary wrapper of your searched result, with string key `-LTR7P8PFWHogjlBENiJ`

So your code currently searches key `review` in the outer dict.

Comment: The question is how would I achieve printing the review? I have not worked with a NSDictionary that is set up this way.